# Using an IN in a where

Tags: php, mysqli, where-clause

I've been having some trouble using an IN in a where clause using MySQLi this is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM core_tags WHERE tag_id IN (1,2,3,4,5) GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tag_popularity ASC
```

If I run this in PHP My Admin then I get 5 results as I would expect. However if I run it in PHP with the following code I only get one result of the tag_id '1'.

Here's my PHP. Originally I was running it using functions in a class but I've hand coded it to test that it wasn't simply an error in my functions with the same problem.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM core_tags WHERE tag_id IN (?) GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tag_popularity ASC';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($rawQuery);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $tag_ids);
$tag_ids = "1,2,3,4,5";
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($tag_id, $tag_name, $tag_desc, $tag_popularity);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s\n", $tag_name);
}

$stmt->close();
die();
```

Anyone have any idea why the mysqli version only returns one row? Using MySQL instead of mysqli works fine as well, same as PHP My Admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a string prepared statement will cause your final SQL to look like:

```
IN ('1,2,3,4,5')
```

with the quotes, which is not what you want. What I'd do is this:

```
$ids= array(1,2,3,4,5);
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM core_tags WHERE tag_id IN (';
$rawQuery .= implode(',',array_fill(0,count($ids),'?'));
$rawQuery .= ') GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tag_popularity ASC';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($rawQuery);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$ids);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($tag_id, $tag_name, $tag_desc, $tag_popularity);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s\n", $tag_name);
}
```

If the `implode array_fill` is confusing, it just is a shorthand way of creating an array of the same size as `$ids` full of `"?"`, then turning them to a csv.

**UPDATE: Non bind params way**

Of course, if you want to skip the bind params nonsense, and you can trust the list of `$ids` to already be sanitized, you can just do this instead, and skip the bind_params section:

```
$rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM core_tags WHERE tag_id IN (';
$rawQuery .= implode(',',$ids);
$rawQuery .= ') GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tag_popularity ASC';
```

If you can't trust the data:

```
function clean_ids(&$item){
 $item = intval($item);
}

$clean_ids = array_walk($ids,'clean_ids');
$rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM core_tags WHERE tag_id IN (';
$rawQuery .= implode(',',$clean_ids);
$rawQuery .= ') GROUP BY tag_id ORDER BY tag_popularity ASC';
```

Comment: Cheers for this it was sort of how I was thinking it may need to be done, but thanks for figuring out exactly it should work. One thought, is there a reason for using implode and array_full instead of something like substr(str_repeat("?,", count($ids)), 0, -1); I don't know enough to know which is better performance wise etc

Comment: @Rob, Personal preference. I like working with arrays. I would consider the question about performance to be a microoptimization. The time PHP takes to do either one is miniscule compared to a db call :-). Also, see the updated answer, I provided two more methods to solve this.

Comment: Cheerrs for the extra examples, that was of course my alternative, but having moved over to prepared statements I wasn't keen to move away from it again. One thing. Your first example gives this error:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

I presume because it uses the same variable each time and thus can't be used by reference or something like that?

Comment: @rob, oh yes, my mistake. Updating main example to use call_user_func_array

Comment: I don't know if you'll reply before I do, but the way around this was to use call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $args); with all the arguments needed to send to bind_param. I will edit my original question with the full answer. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: haha we came to the same conclusion within 2 seconds of each other, very good and once again thankyou very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about PHP, but usually when you create a parameterized query like the one you're creating using only one parameter for the list of options in the 'IN' you would en up with something like:

select * from core_tags WHERE tag_id IN ('1,2,3')

that will not do what you want... you would need to add a parameter to the query for each value in the IN that you want

Comment: That seems to work but makes it very difficult to use when the number of ids will vary from query to query. I'll see if anyone else can offer a better solution, but thankyou for your contribution.

Comment: +1: Jaime, you're right about how standard SQL & parameterized queries are.  @Rob: What you want is dynamic SQL realm; you need to concatenate the string list of values in the IN clause before running the query string in mysqli.

Comment: I usually end up iterating trough the list of values and constructing the IN part kinda by hand in that way... not sure how to do it in PHP though